# Title of video about judgment?

Tags: heaven, afterlife, judgment

Trying to identify (title or anything helpful) a DVD I saw long ago.  Guy gets to (heaven?), is nervous about judgment, meets St. Paul (and others) while waiting.  When his turn comes, all the not-so-cool things he was nervous about are missing from his record.  Plus some of the people in the not-so-cool things are thanking him instead of reprimanding him.

Comment: Was this a movie and was it ever aired on TV?

Comment: DVD shown privately.  Guy who showed it has not responded to my question.  TV, I don’t know.

Comment: When did you view this DVD and when was it made?

Comment: More than four years ago.  To answer when it was made, I’d have to have a copy so I could look at the date.  In which case, I wouldn’t be asking for help finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not have been a DVD.  But I am fairly certain it was the same as ["The Bema" on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14jlmNldGaE).